# Nebular authentication redirect in angular

Tags: angular, nebular

for example i have below urls
home url(default) :  https://sitexxx/home/board/
edit url : https://sitexxx/edit/1223/
When i give edit url to someone, then should able to land on edit page after authentication. But currently they always go to the home page after authentication. With NbLocalStorage configuration, i was able to redirect to specific page after authentication, but this works only user navigated to home page after authentication atlease once.

How to redirect to specific page after Nebular Authentication instead of default page in Angular ?
Any idea ? Thanks.

Thanks

Comment: Is authentication located on a separated path? In this case you can add a parameter like "?origin=url" that you can get in the component and then redirect to the given url. Or you can store the origin url in the localstore.

Comment: thanks. Able to capture the home url after authentication is complete.But not able to capture original url entered by user.Below is the authentication strategy i am using.  
NbAuthModule.forRoot({
      strategies: [
        AzureADAuthStrategy.setup({ name: 'azure', clientId: xxxxxxx,
        authorize: { endpoint: xxxxx,responseType: NbOAuth2ResponseType.CODE,scope: xxxx, redirectUri: xxxxx,
          },token: { class: AuthAzureToken,endpoint: xxxxx,redirectUri: xxx,scope: xxxxx,},refresh: {endpoint:Type: xxxxx,scope: xxx, },  redirect: {success: '/auth/callback',  },     }),   ], }),

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? And I would recommend you reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).